# How to check if there is an active session or not in appwrite?

Tags: appwrite

Like firebase we can check if there is an active session by FirebaseUser. How can we check on start of my MainActivity that if a user is logged in or not. I am working with java, i have not found any proper solution. Appwrite says to use get() but i am not able to understand how to use it. Any help

Comment: 12:02:56.031  W  io.appwrite.exceptions.AppwriteException: User (role: guests) missing scope (account)
12:02:56.032  W   at io.appwrite.Client$awaitResponse$2$1.onResponse(Client.kt:490)
12:02:56.032  W   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
12:02:56.032  W   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
12:02:56.032  W   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
12:02:56.032  W   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
12:02:56.032  I  No sessions Found

Comment: above was the error on appwrite

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, in Appwrite, the typical approach is to call `account.get()` and if it executes successfully, there is an active session and you can send the user to the home page. If `account.get()` throws an exception, there is no active session so you should send the user to the log in page.

Related discussion: https://github.com/appwrite/appwrite/discussions/3938#discussioncomment-3746725

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a short example ;)

```
Future<User?> getUserIfExists() async {
  try {
    final user = await this.account.get();
    return user;
  } on AppwriteException catch (e) {
    if (e.code != 401 || e.type != 'general_unauthorized_scope') rethrow;
  }
  return null;
}
```

So it just catches the Exception if was thrown only because of a non existing session - otherwise you could not tell if it was something else what caused the exception like "no inet connection"

Hope this helps!